# How to write this specific query in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, elmah

I have a piece of SQL code taken from an ELMAH stored procedure under SQL Server:

```
DELETE FROM [ELMAH_Error]
WHERE ErrorId NOT IN (SELECT TOP 100 ErrorId FROM ELMAH_Error ORDER BY TimeUtc DESC)
```

I now migrate a web site to use mysql instead, and I don't know how to translate this code.

I must add the translation after this piece of code:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`b43638b86659eb`@`%` PROCEDURE `elmah_LogError`(
    IN ErrorId CHAR(36), 
    IN Application varchar(60), 
    IN Host VARCHAR(30), 
    IN Type VARCHAR(100), 
    IN Source VARCHAR(60), 
    IN Message VARCHAR(500), 
    IN User VARCHAR(50), 
    IN AllXml TEXT, 
    IN StatusCode INT(10), 
    IN TimeUtc DATETIME
)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `elmah_error` (
        `ErrorId`, 
        `Application`, 
        `Host`, 
        `Type`, 
        `Source`, 
        `Message`, 
        `User`, 
        `AllXml`, 
        `StatusCode`, 
        `TimeUtc`
    ) VALUES (
        ErrorId, 
        Application, 
        Host, 
        Type, 
        Source, 
        Message, 
        User, 
        AllXml, 
        StatusCode, 
        TimeUtc
    );
END
```

I tried adding @Sick's response just before the END statement but SQL Workbench (by alter procedure command) does not see it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent of Sql Server `TOP` Keyword in Mysql is `Limit` and it should be at the end of your query

```
DELETE FROM `ELMAH_Error`
WHERE ErrorId NOT IN (SELECT ErrorId 
                      FROM `ELMAH_Error`
                      ORDER BY TimeUtc DESC LIMIT 100)
```

Comment: This is close to correct, although you should use backticks instead of brackets (`[...]`) around the table name.

Comment: @EdCottrell - Yep missed it :)

Comment: Thanks @Sick. I updated my question to show you a difficulty I have trying your solution.

Comment: ok, I have the reason. MySql version does not support LIMIT. Tried Gordon's code and this one is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support `limit` in certain subqueries.  If that is the case here, then use an explicit join:

```
DELETE e
    FROM ELMAH_Error e LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT ErrorId
          FROM ELMAH_Error
          ORDER BY TimeUtc DESC
          LIMIT 100
         ) ee
         ON ee.ErrorId = e.ErrorId
    WHERE ee.ErrorId IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

The above code assumes that `ErrorId` is unique in the table and doesn't have `NULL` values.  If this is not true, then the query will not work.  (Note:  the assumption that a column called Id is unique and not null seems like a very reasonable.)

```
DELETE e
    FROM ELMAH_Error e LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT TimeUtc
          FROM ELMAH_Error
          ORDER BY TimeUtc DESC
          LIMIT 100
         ) ee
         ON ee.TimeUtc = e.TimeUtc
    WHERE ee.TimeUtc IS NULL;
```

Comment: This code is accepted by MySql server. I checked that generating an error was not broken. It's not. About the deletion of records, I will be able to check that it works later when errors stack up. I will mark your solution as the answer in the meantime.

Comment: It seems there is an issue after all. This code keeps only one single entry in my error table! Any idea?

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac . . . The would occur when the most recent 100 rows all have the same `ErrorId`.

Comment: Hummm, no. At first the table is empty. Then, after a first entry is saved, adding a new entry deletes the previous one. Also, I imagine that Elmah does not create entries with equal ErrorIds (they are guids anyway).

Comment: @NicolasCadilhac . . . This code should work, unless you have duplicates or `NULL` values in `ELMAH_Error`.

Comment: Gordon, there are no NULL or duplicates ID. Just checked it again, now that I have removed your code and that I can see several records.

Answer (score 0):

If the table is really big, then truncating is usually much faster than delete in MySQL. Something like:

```
lock tables ELMAH_Error write;
create temporary table cpy_ELMAH_Error 
   select * from ELMAH_Error order by TimeUtc DESC LIMIT 100;
truncate table ELMAH_Error;
insert into  ELMAH_Error select * from cpy_ELMAH_Error;
drop table cpy_ELMAH_Error;
unlock tables;
```

Comment: Thank you. It is not big right now and it will grow until reaching 100 records. After that, DELETE will ensure not to go over 100.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more somewhat simpler way if you are interested:

```
set @N=0;
delete from ELMAH_Error where (@N:=@N+1) > 101 order by TimeUtc DESC;
```

Comment: I'm still searching a solution. I tried yours and it deletes nothing. Any idea?